# Data doesn't display in order

Tags: java

When my data prints out, its no in order of ORDER BY which i've indicated in my codes.

Here's a few snips of my codes which might help. Mind some of the error as i have to delete some lines before posting.

```
String dataFinder = "SELECT DISTINCT dG2 FROM DAE ORDER BY dG2";

HashMap<String, StringWriter> fSW= new HashMap<String, StringWriter>();     

HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> DGGSW = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();

            this.setSQL(dataFinder);
            ResultSet rs = this.retrieveAllData(handler, tracker);
            while ( rs.next() )
            {
                if ( rs.getString("dG2") != null )
                {
                    fSW.put(rs.getString("dG2").trim().toUpperCase(), new StringWriter());
                    DGGSW.put(rs.getString("dG2").trim().toUpperCase(), new HashMap<String, String>());
                }
            }

            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

            while ( rs.next() )
            {
                String dataList = "";

                if ( rs.getString("diagM") != null )
                    dataList = rs.getString("diagM");
            }

            String resultString = stringWriter.toString();

            for ( String diaG : DDGSW.keySet() )
                resultString += diaG + "," + DDGSW.get(gateNo).toString();

            this.WriteToFile(resultString);
        } 

    }

}
```

Comment: Hashmap is not ordered collection. Order will not be maintained once you will put values in hashmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The selection of your data structure is incorrect.**

You should use [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) in place of [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)(where the order of inserts is not guaranteed to be preserved)if you want the order of your inserts.

Since you are fetching the records in an order and inserting that in a `HashMap`, the records are inserted in a random order, since it is passed through a hashfunction.